# rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan gmaps4raills map display issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Sorry I am a bit of a Rails newbie but have been trying to get gmaps4rails to work with twitter bootstrap and have hit a bit of a dead end. Nothing seems to resolve it or point in the right direction after hours of Googling.I have gone through all the steps before with an un-bootstrapped rails app and it worked, but for some reason the map wont display in the TBS version. 
Just to note I used the rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan template in case there are any known issues with that.

I have included this stylesheet link at the top of my view:

```
<head>
<% content_for :head do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :gmaps4rails -%>
<% end %>
</head>
```

…..

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

In the head of the application.html..erb

```
 <%= yield :head %>
```

In the controllers index action:

```
@json = Outlet.all.to_gmaps4rails
```

and in the model:

```
acts_as_gmappable :position => :location
def gmaps4rails_address
address
end
```

gmaps4rails.css is in the stylesheets folder so should be accessible.

Gemfile

```
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

I also added this gem

```
gem 'thin'
```

Because i was getting another error about the content-length but I'm pretty sure it was unrelated to the gmaps problem (maps don't show up before or after installing this gem)

Also, when I load the app in firefox I can see from the activity in the bottom left of the screen that it appears to be connecting successfully to the Google Maps API and no errors are displayed in the terminal.

This is the terminal output.

```
Started GET "/outlets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-17 21:26:24 +0000
Processing by OutletsController#index as HTML
  Outlet Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "outlets".* FROM "outlets" 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "outlets".* FROM "outlets" 
  Rendered /Users/mikemccann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@myapp/gems/gmaps4rails-1.5.6/app/views/gmaps4rails/_gmaps4rails.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered outlets/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (188.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 212ms (Views: 208.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Really stumped by this one so any help is greatly appreciated!!!
Mike

Comment: What do you see on your screen ? It would be easier if you add your `application.js` and `application.css` files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly giving your map container div a height?  What happens when you look at the HTML in the developer console?  Is anything Gmaps related showing in the map container div?